# how to run javascript and then do a postback?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to create an add to 'favourites'button. When the user clicks this button the image has to be changed ( in js). After that I would like to do a postback the asp.net page? how can I make this work? sofar i got:

aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            function ChangeFavStar() {
                if ($("#btnAddToFavs").attr('src') == 'starempty.jpg') {
                    $("#btnAddToFavs").attr('src') = 'staradded.jpg';
                }
                else {
                    $("#btnAddToFavs").attr('src') = 'starempty.jpg';
                }
                return true;
            }

        });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #btnAddToFavs {
            height: 79px;
            width: 121px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ImageButton ID=btnAddToFavs runat=server 
            OnClientClick="ChangeFavStar();" ImageUrl="~/starempty.jpg"
             Height="74px" Width="109px"  />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

cs behindcode

```
 protected void btnAddToFavs_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
```

Comment: and what is with you click client handler ? it should do exactly what you are asking for

Comment: the only thing it is hidden and won't be launched, remove `$(document).ready(function() { ` wrapper and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may invoke `JavaScript` function but changes on button wont be persisted because of postback. You have to change `ImageUrl` property via C# code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function ChangeFavStar() {
         if ($("#btnAddToFavs").attr('src') == 'starempty.jpg') {
              $("#btnAddToFavs").attr('src') = 'staradded.jpg';
          }
          else {
              $("#btnAddToFavs").attr('src') = 'starempty.jpg';
          }
      }
    </script>
```

Markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAddToFavs" runat=server 
            OnClientClick="ChangeFavStar();" ImageUrl="~/starempty.jpg"
             Height="74px" Width="109px"  />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change function declaration from what you have to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeFavStar() {
            if ($("#btnAddToFavs").attr('src') == 'starempty.jpg') {
                $("#btnAddToFavs").attr('src') = 'staradded.jpg';
            }
            else {
                $("#btnAddToFavs").attr('src') = 'starempty.jpg';
            }
            return true;
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do in this way. You can call Server side click event from JavaScript. you can call this java script like this CLick Me for Postback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function ChangeFavStar() {
         if ($("#btnAddToFavs").attr('src') == 'starempty.jpg') {
              $("#btnAddToFavs").attr('src') = 'staradded.jpg';
          }
          else {
              $("#btnAddToFavs").attr('src') = 'starempty.jpg';
          }

__doPostBack('<%=btnAddToFavs.ClientID %>', '');
      }
    </script>
```